# How to build an efficient notification system?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I need to build a notification system for the users of my website. 
Each user follow some topics, so, when someone post something about a topic, each user which follow this topic have to get a notification.

Now I have a single cronjob, that get the date of the last opening time of the notification of each user and then I get all the post published after this date and then I save it to the notification table of each user

```
---------------     ---------------------------------------
|   new_post   |    |               USERS                 |
---------------     ---------------------------------------
|  id  | post  |    |ud_usr |last_notif_opening(datestamp)|
---------------     ---------------------------------------
|   1  string  |    |   1   |   2017-08-21 10:10:10       |
```

and those, where, i actually store in each one the id of the new posts, so next i get the record of those tables and then i get the text with the relation of the id column.

```
-notification_user1
-notification_user2
-notification_user3
```

I think that isn't a good solution, because maybe a user can't receive his notifications with the right time because the cronjob is cheking the notifications of another user.

Can you guys help me to find a better solution this?

Comment: I would advice that u use web sockets for this

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: It's not exactly your need but you can take a look at [https://notiflare.io](https://notiflare.io?utm_source=stack_overflow&utm_campaign=how-to-build-an-efficient-notification-system). It's a ready to use notification system. It can be a simpler alternative to your problem (if other people have the same) :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use real time solutions , regarding real time web applications there are so many technologies available to use and the most used one on the web currently may be is nodeJs

In PHP when you use some framework like Laravel , there is a strong notification component inside Laravel framework but if you want to use pure PHP or other php frameworks the most effective approach is to utilize WebSockets in PHP .

When using WebSockets you need a websocket server to handle communication between two peers , let me explain exactly about your question in this area .
something that you are looking for is some kind of channels , you want users to subscribe on channel , push notifications into the channel so that the subscribers can get the pushed message or data .
implementing this kind of functionality in PHP is not a hard task , you should use below features :

1. [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) : PHP Websocket Library also it has functionality to make web socket server easily
2. [Thruway](https://github.com/voryx/Thruway) : PHP Library written on top of ratchet when you want to create channels you need this library that supports WAMP(web application messaging protocol) version 2
3. AutobahnJs : for handling client side codes to use WAMP and create channels .

the above features are all you need to work with websockets and channels in PHP . hope it can help you

Comment: you can start studying with WebSockets and WebSocket in PHP then go ahead with ratchet after that study ratchet/Wamp component and then go ahead learning use of thruway with autobahnJs

Comment: let me explain that topic in wamp is exactly channel and they are the same approach just different in naming

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance about this..you told that i need a websocket server, so, assuming i've created the notification system with ratchet etc, what i have to do when i have to put online the new system? Because currently i've my website with cpanel and stop

Comment: if possible , you can ask the hosting company to run your server script on the command line or i don't know may be Cpanel has a feature to run a script like this , may be some kind of cron job or something similar . also you can have the script for websocket server on another server and IP

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [real time notification](https://pusher.com/tutorials/realtime-notifications) or [follow these steps I used in the past.](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet)